# Is it possible to reference custom code in the Where-clause of Neo4J's Cipher Query Language?

Tags: graph, nosql, neo4j

Is it possible to use Neo4J's Cipher Query language (or another declarative language) but still reference custom code snippets (for instance to do custom WHERE-clauses based on, say, the result of a ElasticSearch/Lucene search?)

If other GraphDB's have declarative languages that support this, please shoot. I'm in no way bound to Neo4J.

**Background:**

I'm doing some research whether to include Neo4J in my current stack, which in the backend already consists of ElasticSearch, MongoDB and Redis.

Particulary with Redis' fast set-intersection capability, I could potentially create some rude graph-like querying. (although likely not as performant as a graphDB). I'm a long way in defining a DSL, with the type of queries to support.

However, I'm designing a CMS so contenttypes, and the relationships between these contenttypes which I would like to model with a graph are not known beforehand.

Therefore, the ideal case, of populating the needed Redis collections (with Mongo as source) to support all my quering based on Contenttypes and their relationships that are not known at design time, will be messy to say the least. Hope you're still following.

Which leads me to conclude that another solution may be needed, which is why I'm looking at GraphDb'd and Neo4J in particular (If others are potentially better suited for my use-case do shoot)

Answer (score 0):

If you model your content-types as nodes you don't need to know them beforehand.

User-defined functions in javascript are planned for cypher later this year.

You can use a language like gremlin to declare your functions in groovy though.

You can store the node-id's in redis and then pass in an array of id's returned by redis to a cypher query for further processing.

```
start n=node({ids}) 
match n-[:HAS_TYPE]->content_type<-[:HAS_TYPE]-other_content
return content_type, count(*)
order by count(*) desc
limit 10

parameters: {"ids": [1,2,3,5]}
```

Comment: Content (as in contenttype-instances) would be modeled as nodes. E.g: a particular blogpost would be a node of contenttype 'Blogpost'. You're saying: "If you model your content-types as nodes you don't need to know them beforehand." You mean in Node4J right? If so, indeed, that's why I would like to use Neo4j. With the difference of having content as nodes instead of contenttypes as said above.  BTW: would https://github.com/neo4j/javascript-plugin be the project testing out Gremlin with Javascript or it there a proper issue in the  Gremlin project I could follow?

Comment: I think that plugin has not been developed further. But you can pick it up if it suits your needs.